# Working with timestamp in Excel

Tags: excel, timestamp

I am trying to create to chart of timestamp vs response time.

However, I am running into issues with formatting the timestamp. Though there is a 5 sec difference between the timestamp entries, when I plot the graph with timestamp on x-axis, it takes it as just one unit and the time difference is not visible.

Has this something to do with the formatting? Here is a small sample

1. 13/07/2015 10:49:39 334                         12 secs
2. 13/07/2015 10:49:40 735                          4 secs
3. 13/07/2015 10:49:46 646                          3 secs
4. 13/07/2015 10:49:58 700                          6 secs

Appreciate any assistance!

Comment: Not sure excel can do a chart based on seconds seperation? I just tried, and it seems like the smallest unit of seperation it has is days. I would suggest pulling the "time" out of the timestamp field and turn it into a number, then try that ... might have better luck ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you format your timestamp cells to time format (so you only see the hh:mm:ss), then the Excel graph will change to give you an X-axis in seconds.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I also added the X-Y Scatter plot and it looks better with just the time.